# Can we customize the transaction type or prepend some code format to block in the chaincode to determine the transaction type?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-chaincode

Blocks in hyperledger comprises of fields like header, data and metadata. Block hash doesn't include metadata so can it be changed to have asset type definition to determine the kind of transaction in the block.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you actually could directly send transactions in HLF. You need to invoke chaincode functions. Well ok. The function call is warped into a txn. But I don’t think you could set transaction type.